# openssl not connecting to gmail server

Tags: django, email, openssl, smtp, gmail

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 and openssl 1.1.1

This started when I tried to send an email to myself with Django's `send_mail()` function. The function executed fine, but the email never arrived.  Checking the Postfix log revealed this error:

```
connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4023:1::1a]:25: Connection timed out
```

Trying to diagnose this led to me to running command-line experiments with openssl. The following command fails with a timeout:

```
# openssl s_client -connect smtp.google.com:587 -starttls smtp
4047B9AF807F0000:error:10000067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:127:
4047B9AF807F0000:error:8000006E:system library:BIO_connect:Connection timed out:../crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:125:calling connect()

... (several repeats of the error above) ...

403747797B7F0000:error:10000067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/bio_sock2.c:127:
connect:errno=110
```

(The result was the same using "alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", which was the domain from the postfix log)

I don't think the problem is just my computer or network because trying with "strawberry.active-ns.com" (a domain used by an online example of openssl) works:

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect strawberry.active-ns.com:587
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
```

I have used `send_mail()` from my laptop in the past, and it has worked fine.  Did Google change something?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.